# dlopen doesn't respect `RTLD_LOCAL`?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, glibc, dlopen

I have `A.so`, which links to a particular versioned `libstdc++.so.6` at its own directory (via `rpath` set to `$ORIGIN`).

If I `dlopen` `A.so` alone, it works fine.

If I `dlopen` my system's `libstdc++.so.6` (which is of different version) in `RTLD_LOCAL` mode, and then `dlopen` `A.so`

```
OSError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by A.so)
```

Why doesn't dlopen respect `RTLD_LOCAL`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why doesn't dlopen respect `RTLD_LOCAL`

`RTLD_LOCAL` doesn't mean what you think it means. From `man dlopen`:

```
RTLD_LOCAL
          This is the converse of RTLD_GLOBAL, and the default if
          neither flag is specified.  Symbols defined in this shared
          object are not made available to resolve references in
          subsequently loaded shared objects.
```

Note that this says *nothing* about which library the loader is loading.

The loader will *never* load more than one instance of a given `SONAME` (unless you use a different linker scope using `dlmopen`), so when you `dlopen` system `libstdc++.so.6`, that is the *only* `libstdc++.so.6` you will *ever* get. When you later `dlopen("A.so", ...)`, the runtime loader:

1. Looks for libraries that `A.so` depends on, discovers that `libstdc++.so.6` is among them, and discovers that it *already* has `libstdc++.so.6` loaded, so it doesn't search for, nor load another copy,
2. Looks for *version* symbols that `A.so` requires. It is at this point that you get the error, since `A.so` requires `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` from `libsstdc++.so.6`, and since the already loaded system `libstdc++.so.6` is older and doesn't provide `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` version.
3. Since step #2 failed, your `dlopen` is rejected.

Note that you never get to resolving *any* symbols from `libstdc++.so.6` (where `RTLD_LOCAL` would matter); you fail long *before* that.

Now, what you *probably* are trying to do is build `A.so` in such a way that it can be dynamically loaded into an arbitrary program, possibly one using an older version of `libstdc++.so.6`, without forcing the end-user to update system `libstdc++.so.6`. Unfortunately, this simply *can not* be done.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, why wouldn't that be possible with dlmopen()?  Obviously, you couldn't pass STL types across the interface (i.e. between code using different instances of libstdc++.so), but wouldn't it work for private use within a library?